# fbDidLogin not firing when called from C++ on iPhone app

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++, cocos2d-x, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an app on iOS that works with C++ (a Cocos2DX game). I want to integrate Facebook on it.

I initialize the Facebook iOS SDK as the Facebook developers website indicates it, on a Objective C class. Then I call this Objective-C class from my C++ code, and it seems to work -the Facebook app is opened and asks for authentication and permissions-.

The problem is that the "events" or "callbacks" like fbDidLogin are not called back, or at least I do not have control over them from C++

Do you know if that can be done?

Thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution:

All the Facebook related code must be in the AppDelegate.m Then you can access it from anywhere in your code with this instruction:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate FacebookLogin];
```